# How to load the Zend Framework in my existing project?

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework2, autoload

I'm trying to add Zend to an existing project, and for this I guess I need the autoloader. So I tried including various files in [the Loader folder](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/tree/master/library/Zend/Loader) and running the register() method from them;

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../code/external/zend/library/Zend/Loader/ModuleAutoloader.php';
\Zend\Loader\ModuleAutoloader::register();
```

gets me:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message
>   'Passed array does not specify an existing static method (first array
>   member is not a valid class name or object)' in
>   /home/kramer65/myproject/code/external/zend/library/Zend/Loader/ModuleAutoloader.php:312

and

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../code/external/zend/library/Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';
\Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader::register();
```

gets me:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message
>   'Passed array does not specify an existing static method (first array
>   member is not a valid class name or object)' in
>   /home/kramer65/myproject/code/external/zend/library/Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php:243

So I checked out line 243 from StandardAutoloader.php, which reads:

```
spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'autoload'));
```

I guess I need to provide some array, but I'm unsure which one and how? Could anybody give me some more appreciated guidance in how to load Zend in my project? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
Let me add that I ask this about Zend 2.

Comment: Take a look here, similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542527/load-zend-framework-component-in-existing-project

Comment: @VikingBlooded - Yeah I saw that question as well, but that is about Zend 1, which seems to have different loader structure. Would you have any idea about this in Zend 2?

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.loader.class-map-autoloader.html take a look at the configuration options section and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `register()` statically, but it is not a static method, which is the cause of the error. I've not done this before, but I think you want something more like this:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../code/external/zend/library/Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';
$loader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader(array('autoregister_zf' => true));
$loader->register();
```